# Is it possible to know if an iframe redirects the user to a different page

Tags: javascript, html

In a browser is it possible using javascript to know if an iframe with a given url displays an Html page or if it redirects the user to another domain?

I have an html page with an iframe to a given url on another domain. I know i can't access to the content of the page or the src attribute of the iframe tag. I just want to know if the server answers me with an HTTP 200 or HTTP 301 or HTTP 302 code. Is it possible ?